# It works, but sometimes it stops when I click on a button

Tags: html, debugging, web

my code basically works, but when I click the start button a few times, so for example I click on start, the randomnumbers appear, then I type in a number, click on fertig, and make these steps for a few times again. After these few times the start button is "stuck" when I click on it. So I click on it, it goes down, but not up again, you understand ? :-)

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Der Einmaleins - Trainer</title>  
  <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
  <script src = "script1m1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Der Einmaleins - Trainer</h1> 
  <button type="button" onclick = "start();">Start</button> 
  <button type = "button" onclick = "fertig();">Fertig!</button>
  <input id = "erginput" type = "number">

  <label id = "rn1"></label>  
  <label id = "multiplication"></label>
  <label id = "rn2"></label>  
  <br>
  <label id = "feedback"></label>


 </body>

</html>
```

Here's the JS:

```
var randomnumber1;
var randomnumber2;

function start() {  
  randomnumber1 = getrn();
  randomnumber2 = getrn();
  while(randomnumber1 == 5 || randomnumber2 == 5 ){
     if (randomnumber1 == 5){randomnumber1 = getrn();}
     else{randomnumber2 == getrn();}

}
document.getElementById("rn1").innerHTML = randomnumber1;
document.getElementById("multiplication").innerHTML = "x";
document.getElementById("rn2").innerHTML = randomnumber2;

}

function getrn(){
  var min = 3;
  var max = 10;
  var zufallszahl = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
 return zufallszahl;
}

function ergebnispruefen(zahl,faktor1,faktor2){
  var ergebnisrichtig = faktor1 * faktor2;
  if (zahl == ergebnisrichtig){
       document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "Richtig!";
       document.getElementById("feedback").style.color = "Lime";
  }else{
       document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "Falsch,denk  nach!";
     document.getElementById("feedback").style.color = "red";
}

}

function fertig(){
  var ergebnis = document.getElementById("erginput").value;  
  ergebnispruefen(ergebnis,randomnumber1,randomnumber2);

}
```

console.log("Thanks in advance! :-)");

Ji W

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey, at first, when it works, there are no errors, but when the button is stuck it says "hit ctrl+p to open a file"